# Doubts about sexual orientation

Tags: homosexuality

Assalam alaikum my brother,
I recently had doubts about my sexual orientation the other day, but I am heterosexual(I like the opposite sex), but for some reason every day there are questions about homosexuality, although I have never liked guys sexually. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Wa Alaikkum wa Salaam.

I think, just study and recite, Surah Al nas (114th Sura of Quran). These whisperings try to retract people.